# jQuery 1.9 appending html into page and then a script, both dependant on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Working on upgrading from jQuery 1.8 to 1.9 and running into a problem. We have certain pages that can be loaded into a modal on any given page. We do this using ajax and then parsing out the `script` elements from the returned html. We then append the html to the page and then we append the scripts to the `head`. It would look something like this:

```
controller_element = $( html )
body_scripts = $( controller_element, "script" ).remove()
$( ".modal-body" ).append controller_element
$("head").append body_scripts
```

This was working prior in 1.8 but we're now running into problems in 1.9. The issue seems to revolve around document ready events. The html has some inline javascript that needs to run on document ready, which runs right after the append which seems to be right according to documentation. What really needs to happen is it needs to run after the javascript scripts are appended to the `head`. And we can't just switch the order of these two lines, because the js needs to run after the html is loaded to bind events to the dom. Really, some thoughts on what might have happened between 1.8 and 1.9 would be very helpful. Or if anyone else successfully implemented loading a new page via ajax into a modal, I'd like to hear implementations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I believe I just figured it out. We had been parsing out the scripts from the body like this `body_scripts = $( controller_element, "script" ).remove()`, and the `controller_element = $( html )`. Changing the parsing to `body_scripts = $( "script", controller_element ).remove()` has fixed the problem for me. Should the 1.8 method have even worked?

So essentially, you need to remove all `script` including inline from your html. Append the html, then append the scripts. The html will now be ready to be bound to any events and the inline scripts can run with everything loaded.